# How to check if a shared library is linked with -Bsymbolic?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries

How can I check if a shared library is linked with a `-Bsymbolic` flag?

I've tried `nm <path/to/lib.so> | grep -i symbolic`, however, there is no output for libraries that are linked with `-Wl,-Bsymbolic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can examine dynamic section of the library:

```
$ readelf -d a.out | grep SYMBOLIC
 0x0000000000000010 (SYMBOLIC)           0x0
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              SYMBOLIC
```